# Comfortable Mexican Sofa - Accessing cms content from the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm having trouble accessing the cms content from the app.

This is the rails code, from where I wanna access the content of the cms.

```
# GET /songs
# GET /songs.json
def index
  @songs = Song.all
  render cms_page: 'songs/index', cms_site: (Rails.env.development? ? 'songs-en' : nil)
end
```

But I always get the following:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: The extracted source in the image doesn't seem to match the code example. I assume the error is the same for both `songs` and `songs/index`? Have you tried `/songs/index` (note leading `/`)?

Comment: @CharlieEgan : 
Oh darn, sorry... seems like I uploaded the wrong image... So yes I have tried nearly everything, if I change the code to **/songs/index**, I will then get **Cannot find CMS Page at /songs/index**

I'm just wondering that I can't find an in-depth example of this "accessing CMS content from the app" kind of thing.

Comment: My goodness, seems like not only I must put **/** at the beginning of the **songs/index**, but I also have to put another **/** at the end of it. So the final form (that works for me) looks like **/songs/index/**. Thanks everybody.

Comment: If a trailing slash is required then you might consider updating the docs here https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Accessing-cms-content-from-the-app or filing an issue to open discussion on the matter. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

My goodness, seems like not only I must put **/** at the beginning of the **songs/index**, but I also have to put another **/** at the end of it. So the final form (that works for me) looks like **/songs/index/**.

Thanks everybody. Many thanks to @CharlieEgan

Hendry I.